# glutPostRedisplay is not invoking display callback until a mouse event or window resize event

Tags: opengl

From the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247081/glutpostredisplay-not-working-inside-a-loop) I get to know the functioning of glutPostRedisplay API. It is understood that this API is not calling the callback instead it just set a flag so that the main loop will call its callback next time. The pseudo code is:

```
void onNewFrame(int x, int y)
{
  // Do calculations
  std::cout << " New Frame " << endl;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
  std::cout << " Display " << endl;
  // Calculations & opengl operations
}
```

Here `display()` is the API registered with `glutDisplayFunc()` in `main()`. While executing in the console, I can see " New Frame" getting printed as expected but unable to see "Display" getting printed. The `glutPostRedisplay()` API would have set the flag but in my case the `display()` is only executed when there is a mouse event or when the window size is changed.

So why is this happening? Is it because the main loop is not getting executed untill a mouse event or window resize ?

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation I found that the problem was with the capability of the computer. When I re-run the same code on high configuration PC, the re-rendering is very fast. In that case the display function is called quite often.